# How to mean center a column with varying duplicates?

Tags: r, dataframe, centering

Suppose we have a dataframe `df` with a structure like a the following:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
subj   age   trial    
 A       9      1       
 A       9      2      
 A       9      3       
 B      10      1
 B      10      2
 C       8      1       
 C       8      2
 C       8      3
 C       8      4")
```

How to elegantly remove the mean age of all subjects from each subject so that the resulting dataframe would look like below?

```
subj   age   trial    
 A       0      1       
 A       0      2      
 A       0      3       
 B       1      1
 B       1      2
 C      -1      1       
 C      -1      2
 C      -1      3
 C      -1      4
```

**P.S.** - Notice that each subject (first column) has multiple rows, and thus the associated age (second column) is repeated. The number of repetitions depends on the number of trials (third column) and is different across subjects. Thus, the average average across all subjects should be computed without those duplicates.

Comment: what is the logic?

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(mean_age = mean(age[trial == 1], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(age = age - mean_age)
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  subj    age trial mean_age
  <chr> <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
1 A         0     1        9
2 A         0     2        9
3 A         0     3        9
4 B         1     1        9
5 B         1     2        9
6 C        -1     1        9
7 C        -1     2        9
8 C        -1     3        9
9 C        -1     4        9
```

**EDIT**:
With a random `trial` per `subj`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(subj) %>%
  mutate(trial_sample = sample(trial, 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(mean_age = mean(age[trial_sample], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(age = age - mean_age)
```

Data (thanks goes to @Marek Fiolka):

```
df = read.table(
  header = TRUE,text="
subj   age   trial    
 A       9      1       
 A       9      2      
 A       9      3       
 B      10      1
 B      10      2
 C       8      1       
 C       8      2
 C       8      3
 C       8      4    
") %>% as_tibble()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just added some additional mark at the end of my original post to clarify the situation. Any further suggestion?

Comment: Not sure if I've understood the task. Let me know if that is closer to what you need.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to have a solution that does not rely on one particular trial (e.g., `trial == 1`)? Any base `R` solution?

Comment: So, any random trial?

Comment: Some subjects may not have a particular trial number (e.g., 1) due to missing data.

Comment: Please check out the edit - that what you need?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `mutate` function as below. However, note that the mean of your age variable is `8.777778`. So you won't get exactly output as you expect.

```
library(tidyverse)

df = read.table(
  header = TRUE,text="
subj   age   trial    
 A       9      1       
 A       9      2      
 A       9      3       
 B      10      1
 B      10      2
 C       8      1       
 C       8      2
 C       8      3
 C       8      4    
") %>% as_tibble()

df %>% mutate(age = age - mean(age))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  subj     age trial
  <chr>  <dbl> <int>
1 A      0.222     1
2 A      0.222     2
3 A      0.222     3
4 B      1.22      1
5 B      1.22      2
6 C     -0.778     1
7 C     -0.778     2
8 C     -0.778     3
9 C     -0.778     4
```

Even if you use rounding

```
df %>% mutate(age = age - round(mean(age)))
```

output

```
 A tibble: 9 x 3
  subj    age trial
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 A         0     1
2 A         0     2
3 A         0     3
4 B         1     1
5 B         1     2
6 C        -1     1
7 C        -1     2
8 C        -1     3
9 C        -1     4
```

If you absolutely must get the result as shown in the question, you must subtract 1 from the results <0.

```
df %>% mutate(age = age - round(mean(age)),
              age = ifelse(age<0, age-1, age))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  subj    age trial
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 A         0     1
2 A         0     2
3 A         0     3
4 B         1     1
5 B         1     2
6 C        -2     1
7 C        -2     2
8 C        -2     3
9 C        -2     4
```

### Update 1

If you don't want to use information from the `trial` variable, you can do something like this:

```
mage = df %>% 
  distinct(subj, age) %>% 
  pull(age) %>% mean()

df %>% mutate(age = age - mage)
```

or like this:

```
mage = df %>% 
  group_by(subj) %>% 
  summarise(age = min(age)) %>% 
  pull(age) %>% mean()

df %>% mutate(age = age - mage)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  subj    age trial
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 A         0     1
2 A         0     2
3 A         0     3
4 B         1     1
5 B         1     2
6 C        -1     1
7 C        -1     2
8 C        -1     3
9 C        -1     4
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just added some additional mark at the end of my original post to clarify the situation. Any further suggestion?

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out the mistake in the final result. Corrected now.